# Android selectableItemBackground no glow effect on long press

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use the RecyclerView in an Android app.
I imported the RecyclerView sample project into Android Studio, and it works fine.

I want to make the items in the recycler view to react visually when the user long presses them. In order to do that, I set the background of the view to `selectableItemBackground`. I made these modifications:

- inside text_row_item.xml, I added this line on the FrameLayout tag:

  `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`
- inside CustomAdapter.java, I added a long click listener on the FrameLayout:

  `v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getPosition() + " long clicked.");
          return true;
      }
  });`

If I run the modified sample on a Lollipop emulator, I get the nice ripple effect when I long press the items in the recycler view.

But if I run the app on a KitKat emulator, I don't get the glow effect that comes with KitKat. The item in the list gets darker when I long-press it, and the long click listener does run, but I expected the color to glow as the long press was happening.

Here is a gif of what I'm seing:
[image: long press animation not working]

Why does `selectableItemBackground` not run the glow effect on KitKat? How can I get it to work on both KitKat and Lollipop?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
  android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
  android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
  android:clickable="true"
```

in  your recyleview row layout

Comment: This does not work. If I add these attributes to the FrameLayout tag, nothing happens. I still get the same behavior on KitKat (no animation on long press).

Comment: clickable="true" made it work for my case, thanks! Still doesn't solve topic owner's problem though

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was using `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` style. After changing it to `android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar` the ripple effect is working.

So the only thing that i had to do was adding:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar
```

into `application` node in Manifest.xml

Or if you use a custom `styles.xml` you can just use the `parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"`